# Why does this datalog query aggregate?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datomic, datalog, datascript

[From https://github.com/tonsky/datascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript)

```
(->
 (d/q '[:find ?color (max ?amount ?x) (min ?amount ?x)
        :in   [[?color ?x]] ?amount]
      [[:red 10]  [:red 20] [:red 30] [:red 40] [:red 50]
       [:blue 7] [:blue 8]]
      4)
 pr-str
 js/console.log)
;;; ([:red [20 30 40 50] [10 20 30 40]] [:blue [7 8] [7 8]]) 

(->
 (d/q '[:find ?color (max ?amount ?x) (min ?amount ?x)
        :in   [[?color ?x]] ?amount]
      [[:red 10]  [:red 20] [:red 30] [:red 40] [:red 50]
       [:blue 7] [:blue 8]]
      3)
 pr-str
 js/console.log)
;;; ([:red [30 40 50] [10 20 30]] [:blue [7 8] [7 8]]) 

(->
 (d/q '[:find ?color (max ?amount ?x) (min ?amount ?x)
        :in   [[?color ?x]] ?amount]
      [[:red 10]  [:red 20] [:red 30] [:red 40] [:red 50]
       [:blue 7] [:blue 8]]
      2)
 pr-str
 js/console.log)
;;; ([:red [40 50] [10 20]] [:blue [7 8] [7 8]])
```

So, this isn't a question about what it is doing, this is a question of how (or at least why) it is doing it. max and min are functions that return the maximum or minimum of their following integers, respectively. How is `?amount` getting factored into limiting the aggregation count? Why are these things aggregating anyway? How is the code being run such that it aggregates. I really don't see how this code is flowing to generate the results it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` and `min` are [overloaded](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#sec-4-17-2) in datomic queries.

The unary `(min ?x)` and `(max ?x)` functions aggreate to return a single number.

The binary `(min ?n ?x)` and `(max ?n ?x)` functions aggreate to return a collection of items limited in length by `?n`.

Comment: to clarify: (max N coll) is top N values of coll. Same for min, it’s N lowest of coll.